# Efficient way to check if array is binary

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an sparse array of frequencies that is being constantly updated, and I'm trying to check if a duplicate exists after each update. Using the frequency array, I'm attempting to determine whether or not the array contains elements greater than one. Since the array is sparse and very large, it's costly to iterate over the entire array

Is there an efficient way to do this (bit manipulation or some data structure that is efficient for multiple queries like a binary indexed tree)?

EDIT: I'm updating a frequency array so I'm looking for an element greater than zero.

Comment: Describe the updates. What are you doing with this array? Why can't you just record the fact that you're making a value greater than 1 at the time you perform that update?

Comment: Can you further explain the question ? Are you looking for element greater than 0 or element with frequency greater than 1?

Comment: why you are not collect info that element present duplicate or not during update.Mantain a bit array and first time make it 1 and second time if it see 1 then emit as duplicate element??

Comment: just keep track of the number of elements in the frequency array that are greater than 1.